# if statement in sql query

Tags: .net

I have two columns in the database: `campus1` and `campus2`, I want to write a query to do the following scenario:

> If `campus2` is null then only compare `campus1` data, else compare both `campus1` and `campus2` data.

I wrote the query like below but got error message on it.

```
select * from tbl1 where 
case when  campus2 is null then (campus1=@campus or campus1 is null)
else
   (campus1=@campus or campus1 is null) and (campus1=@campus or campus2 is null)
end
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: that doesn't make sense - even if it compiled, the conditions in your `else` clause cover the condition you seem to be checking for above it.

Comment: hrmm, don't think you need case statement for that. how about select * from tbl1 where (campus2 is null or campus2 = @campus2) and campus1 = @campus1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a case statement here just write out the boolean logic

```
WHERE
(campus2 is null
      AND
   (campus1=@campus or campus1 is null))
OR
(campus2 is not null
        AND 
   (campus1=@campus or campus1 is null)                 
   and campus2=@campus)
)
```

As a side note if you really want to use a `Case` statement in a `Where` clause you typically write it in this form

```
 WHERE
        CASE WHEN condition THEN expression
             ELSE otherExpression
         END = @SomeParameter
```

This evaluates several conditions into one value to be compared against a parameter